# How to sum two columns in Sqlite for my android apps

Tags: android, sqlite

Please can you help me about simple sum two columns `KEY_COL2` and `KEY_COL3` and show result in `KEY_COL4`?

With this code I defintly doing somtehing wrong:

```
public Cursor getAllData() {                
    String sum ="UPDATE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " SET " + KEY_COL4 + " = " + KEY_COL2 + " + " + KEY_COL3;
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_COL1, KEY_COL2, KEY_COL3, KEY_COL4},null, null, null, null, sum);                     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the sum into your projection and alias it AS KEY_COL4:

```
public Cursor getAllData() {
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_COL1, KEY_COL2, KEY_COL3, KEY_COL2 + " + " + KEY_COL3 + “ AS “ + KEY_COL4}, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

if you actually want to update the data in the database, that will have to be done in a separate operation.